# kendo combobox with selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, kendo-ui

I am trying to automate Kendro UI application using selenium. I am not sure if the selenium is the right tool to use for Kendro UI application.

Could you please help me to select a Kendro UI Combobox dropdown value with selenium.

I have tried multiple ways and none of them worked so far.

**My Code:**
I clicked on the arrow from the dropdown and wait for few seconds and then try to select a value.
But the issue is, for some reason, dropdown it works 4 out of 10 times. So this is not a right solution

```
WebElement firstDropDown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//innova-combobox-input[@name='LHSCID']//span[@class='k-select']"));

firstDropDown.click();
new WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'LHSC 1000 Technician Site A')]")))

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'LHSC 1000 Technician Site A')]")).isDisplayed();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'LHSC 1000 Technician Site A')]")).click();
```

**Below is HTML code on the page for the dropdown:**

```
<input name="{{::$ctrl.name}}_input" class="k-input innova-invalid" type="text" autocomplete="off" title="" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" style="" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="d5147cf1-35ff-4160-ad0f-c164916f59c7" xpath="1">
```

**And The dropdown values**

```
<ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-live="polite" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox" style="" xpath="1">
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-focused" data-offset-index="0" id="d5147cf1-35ff-4160-ad0f-c164916f59c7" style=""></li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="1">
<span ng-bind="dataItem.Display"></span>
</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="2" style=""></li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="3"></li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="4"></li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="5"></li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="6"></li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="7"></li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="8"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Below is the sample demo HTML page with simillar objects https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/index

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Since this is a complex application there are multiple ways we can try to resolve this.

Fairly simple one to try is just clear and sendKeys.

```
WebElement firstDropDown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[text() = 'T-shirt Fabric']//following::input)[1]"));
firstDropDown.click();
firstDropDown.clear();
firstDropDown.sendKeys("Cotton");
```

If you get StaleElementException, try using findElement in every line.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[text() = 'T-shirt Fabric']//following::input)[1]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[text() = 'T-shirt Fabric']//following::input)[1]")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[text() = 'T-shirt Fabric']//following::input)[1]")).sendKeys("Cotton");
```

If this option doesnt work in your application, try using Actions class.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement firstDropDown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[text() = 'T-shirt Fabric']//following::input)[1]"));
action.moveToElement(firstDropDown).click().build().perform(); 
action.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).release().build().perform();
action.sendKeys("Cotton").build().perform();
action.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
```

You can probably make this into a method and reuse it for every dropdown like this.